Partial specialization of a class for pointer to members
I'm trying to create a function object where, given a pointer to a member, it calls std::hash of the pointed-to member (or the result of calling the function member), but there's something wrong about the partial specializations and it doesn't compile:
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template<auto MemberPtr>
struct hash_member_t;

template<class R, class C>
struct hash_member_t<R C::*Member>
{
    constexpr std::size_t operator()(C const& a) const noexcept
    { return std::hash<R>{}(a.*Member); }
};

template<class R, class C>
struct hash_member_t<R (C::*Member)()>
{
    constexpr std::size_t operator()(C const& a) const noexcept
    { return std::hash<R>{}(a.*Member()); }
};

template<auto Member>
inline constexpr hash_member_t hash_member = hash_member_t<Member>{};
    
struct A
{
    int* a = nullptr;
};

int main(int, char**)
{ 
    A a;
    std::cout << hash_member<&A::a>(a) << '\n';
    return 0;
}

Compilation error:
main.cpp:8:34: error: template argument 1 is invalid
    8 | struct hash_member_t<R C::*Member>
      |                                  ^
main.cpp:15:38: error: template argument 1 is invalid
   15 | struct hash_member_t<R (C::*Member)()>
      |                                      ^
main.cpp: In instantiation of 'constexpr const hash_member_t<...auto...> hash_member<&A::a>':
main.cpp:32:18:   required from here
main.cpp:22:32: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct hash_member_t<&A::a>'
   22 | inline constexpr hash_member_t hash_member = hash_member_t<Member>{};
      |                                ^~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:5:8: note: declaration of 'struct hash_member_t<&A::a>'
    5 | struct hash_member_t;
      |        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~

The above is compiled with g++. With clang++:
main.cpp:8:28: error: type-id cannot have a name
struct hash_member_t<R C::*Member>
                           ^~~~~~
main.cpp:8:22: error: template argument for non-type template parameter must be an expression
struct hash_member_t<R C::*Member>
                     ^~~
main.cpp:4:15: note: template parameter is declared here
template<auto MemberPtr>
              ^
main.cpp:15:28: error: expected unqualified-id
struct hash_member_t<R (C::*Member)()>
                           ^
main.cpp:15:29: error: use of undeclared identifier 'Member'
struct hash_member_t<R (C::*Member)()>
                            ^
main.cpp:22:46: error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'hash_member_t<&A::a>'
inline constexpr hash_member_t hash_member = hash_member_t<Member>{};
                                             ^
main.cpp:32:18: note: in instantiation of variable template specialization 'hash_member' requested here
    std::cout << hash_member<&A::a>(a) << '\n';
                 ^
main.cpp:5:8: note: template is declared here
struct hash_member_t;
       ^
5 errors generated.

What's wrong with the syntax or the usage context?

you are mixing non-type and type template arguments

@463035818_is_not_an_ai You are right, the specialization should be an actual address. Thank you.

struct hash_member_t<R C::*Member> and struct hash_member_t<R (C::*Member)()> are supplying types, but the template expects an object since the primary template is a deduced non type template parameter

On a side note: a.*Member() needs to be (a.*Member)() since the function call operator has a higher precedence than the pointer-to-member operator.

You are confusing non-type and type template arguments.
This template
template<auto MemberPtr> struct hash_member_t;

Has a non-type argument. Later you try to specialize it for types. I suppose there is a nicer way to write it, this is just what I got after fixing your code:
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template <typename T,T member> struct hash_member_impl;

template<class R, class C,R C::*member>
struct hash_member_impl<R C::*,member>
{
    constexpr std::size_t operator()(C const& a) const noexcept
    { return std::hash<R>{}(a.*member); }
};

template<class R, class C,R (C::*member)()>
struct hash_member_impl<R (C::*)(),member>
{
    constexpr std::size_t operator()(C const& a) const noexcept
    { return std::hash<R>{}(a.*member()); }
};


template<auto MemberPtr>
using hash_member = hash_member_impl<decltype(MemberPtr),MemberPtr>;

struct A
{
    int* a = nullptr;
};

int main(int, char**)
{ 
    A a;
    std::cout << hash_member<&A::a>{}(a) << '\n';
    return 0;
}

Live Demo
The important line is this
template<auto MemberPtr>
using hash_member = hash_member_impl<decltype(MemberPtr),MemberPtr>;

Your argument is a value, but you want to specialize on its type and this is how you get both the type and value from the auto non-type argument.

As pointed out in the comments and the accepted answer, the problem was that the template parameter is a value, and so the partial specialization requires an actual value, like an actual pointer-to-member, but I intented to detect the type of the received pointer.
For someone with a similar problem that wants to see other ways to solve the problem, this is the solution I finally used for myself:
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template<auto MemberPtr>
struct hash_member_t
{
    template<class T>
    constexpr std::size_t operator()(T const& a) const noexcept
    { return _call(a, MemberPtr); }

private:
    template<class R, class C>
    constexpr std::size_t _call(C const& a, R C::*) const noexcept
    { return std::hash<R>{}(a.*MemberPtr); }
    
    template<class R, class C>
    constexpr std::size_t _call(C const& a, R (C::*)() const) const noexcept
    { return std::hash<R>{}((a.*MemberPtr)()); }
    
    template<class R, class C>
    constexpr std::size_t _call(C const& a, R (C::*)() const noexcept) const noexcept
    { return std::hash<R>{}((a.*MemberPtr)()); }
};

template<auto Member>
inline constexpr hash_member_t hash_member = hash_member_t<Member>{};
    
struct A
{
    int a = 8;
    std::string f() const noexcept { return "hi"; }
};

int main(int, char**)
{ 
    A a;
    std::cout << hash_member<&A::a>(a) << ' ' << hash_member<&A::f>(a) << '\n';
    return 0;
}

This prints "8 11290347552884584064".
